# Querying an oracle Name column from A through K

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a name column in one of the table.
I wish to have 3 checkboxes in UI like A-K, L-S, T-Z.

Is there a way to filter the data using Oracle 10g with three seperate SQLs?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using `REGEXP_LIKE`. For instance.

```
select n
  from T1
 where regexp_like(n, '^[A-K]')
```

To make matching process case-insensitive just add 'i' after a regular expression

```
select n
  from T1
 where regexp_like(n, '^[A-K]', 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nicholas.

BTW I have found the answer after experimenting sometime.

```
select empName from emp where empName between 'A%' and 'S%'
```

Case-insensitive query:

```
select empName from emp where upper(empName) between 'A%' and 'S%'
```